# Expected str bytes or os.pathlike object not builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python

Just want to count all the code lines of a single file that is about a bubble sort program and measures the productivity of itself. I have a method that is supposed to do that, but when I run the program on the console appears 
This is my code:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
def bubblesort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i] > alist[i + 1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i + 1]
                alist[i + 1] = temp

alist = [2, 5, 10, 3, 1, 4]
bubblesort(alist)
print(alist)
end = timer()

time= end - start
print("The excecution time is: " + str(time))

performance= 1/time

print("The performance: " + str(performance))

def count_lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        cnt = sum(1 for line in f)
        print(f'There are {cnt} lines in {filename}')

print(count_lines(timer))
```

> ```
> "Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File ".\timer.py", line 32, in <module> print(count_lines(timer)) 
> File ".\timer.py", line 28, in count_lines 
> with open(filename) as f: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not builtin_function_or_method".
> ```

Comment: Why are you passing timer function as an argument?

Comment: Cause that's the name of the file

Comment: Use `__file__` or `'timer.py'`

Comment: Then pass it as a string e.g. `"timer"`

Comment: My mistake. Just need to change the name of the file, because it was taking it as a call to the function timer :p Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The timer variable should contain a path like string, as it is required to open a file object. But what you are passing is a builtin method `timer`. So change the argument to a path of a file and the code will work just fine.